# Can connect to sftp server through loopback, but not from the outside

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, sftp

I've set up an SFTP server, and the only way I seem to be able to connect to it is from the local machine itself through loopback, which is quite confounding.

The SFTP server is not the standard linux sftp server. It's an apache sftp server running inside a spring-boot application which also has common FTP as well as https endpoints. Ubuntu's SSH is additionally runnig on the system on port 22. The SFTP endpoint of the application is currently mapped to port 2222, though that is easily changed.

The machine the application is running on is an AWS EC2 instance, though after becoming aware of the problem I realised that I can reproduce it on my development machine. Inbound traffic on port 2222 is allowed for all IPs.
The server has a keypair, though only to establish its identity to clients. Clients authenticate by password.

If I connect to the SFTP endpoint from the machine the server is running on via loopback, everything is working nicely:

```
sftp -oPort=22222 -vvv user@domainname.net
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.8, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "domainname.net" port 22222
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to domainname.net [127.0.0.1] port 22222.
debug1: Connection established.
```

A bit more logging follows, then the password prompt, all very normal.
If I however try to connect from another machine, or from the same machine but using the public IP instead of the domain name so it doesn't get resolved as 127.0.0.1, all I get is this:

```
sftp -oPort=12 -vvv user@<pu.bl.ic.ip>
OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "domainname.net" port 2222
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to domainname.net [<pu.bl.ic.ip>] port 12.
debug1: connect to address <pu.bl.ic.ip> port 2222: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host domainname.net port 2222: Connection refused
```

As mentioned earlier, the firewall for the port is open. The behaviour when it is closed and the port can't be reached at all is different, so I'm pretty sure that's not the problem.

The apache sshd server doesn't log anything about the interaction, not even on TRACE, which makes me suspect that it never actually gets the request and it's shot down by something else beforehand.
I tried to do a port forwarding, so that I connect to port 12 from the outside and then it gets routed to 2222, which is how we handle normal FTP connections, but that behaves the exact same way.

Does anybody have any ideas what could be shooting down that connection, or any idea how I can diagnose the issue further?

Comment: Did you check the logfile(s) of the sftp service? Could the port be blocked by a firewall?

Comment: sftp normally connects to ssh (ie port 22) on the server, and the sshd configuration on that server determines what subsystem will handle the sftp.  In my case, I have "Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server".  What do you have configured?  Concerning the firewall, if ssh is working, you're good to go.

Comment: As mentioned, this is a separate server to the ubuntu ssh service, and therefore using a different port. The firewall is open though, the behaviour when running into a closed firewall is quite different from what I'm observing (also I've checked a couple dozen times).

Answer (score 0):

So, the mystery is solved. It had to do with an apache sshd configuration which I accidentally copied over from an example.
In short, the SshServer.host property does not configure anything about the host of the *server*, rather it configures another host *as a valid client*, so only that host is able to connect.
Once I removed that configuration, connection from anywhere worked just fine.